# How to create dropdown text within a TextView - Android

Tags: android, textview, spinner

I'd like to create a `TextView` in Android which, when clicked on, shows the rest of the text ie similar to the hide/show of import statements, where
clicking on the minus/plus shows/hides the rest of the import statements.
I want this so as to save space on the screen!
I've seen examples with `Textview` and `Spinner` - but these are creating lists to choose items from - I just want a simple hide/show, with a title showing, and an arrow or minus/plus sign to hide/show the full document.

Comment: can you able to point to what you are trying , i am asking bez in your header your are telling one thing and in description some thing complex

Comment: well you can create a TextView and a button with + sign when the button is click use textView.setText("Something") to change the text whatever you want and change the sign of button to - and toggle back and forth like that

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Instead of creating custom textview, just create a custom layout, which has two textviews in it.  You can write methods to set/get texts and show/hide any text views present in the layout.

Comment: I've now used a Button for the title, and a TextView set to invisible.

Comment: Use toggle button in this case

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom listview adapter, within the view method add reference/declare your plus/minus buttons, within the onClick statement (inside adapter) add methods for the plus and minus which will switch layouts depending on which is 'clicked' i.e. when plus clicked execute alternative layout, when minus selected execute standard layout.
Theres plenty online resources on creating custom adapters if your unsure..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:


XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expandableTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/expandBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/plusIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
    final int MIN_CHARS = 10;
    String fullText;
    boolean isExpanded;

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expandableTextView);
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.expandBtn);

    fullText = textView.getText().toString();
    textView.setText(fullText.substring(0,MIN_CHARS));
    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.plusIcon);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isExpanded = ! isExpanded;
            imageButton.setImageResource(isExpanded?R.drawable.minusIcon:R.drawable.plusIcon);
            textView.setText(isExpanded?fullText:fullText.substring(0,MIN_CHARS));
        }
    });
```